# Validating a comma separated number up to 1,000 but not 0 value

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a RegEx to validate a number from 1 to 1,000 and comma is included only for 1,000 and any other inputs like 0, 2000, 100.9 so on it should throw error.

I tried using:

```
Regex = "[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)"
```

but it failed for `100`, `200`

Comment: Why are you using regex to validate this? Can you please show your code?

Comment: What are other valid and invalid values?

Comment: from 1 to 1,000 it should accept all the values.

Comment: Pattern pattern;
   Matcher matcher;
   final String num_Pattern = "([1-9])00(,[1-9])00)";

Comment: upto 1000 (exclusive) you have only one number that may have a comma...

Comment: Ok, I think you are looking for `(?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})`. Or `^(?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})$` for checking an individual string. If you do not need to match 1,000, remove it from the regex.

Comment: Yea i am looking for validating number from 1to 1,000 and comma is included only for 1,000 and any other inputs like 0, 2000, 100.9 so on it should throw error. when i enter 0 as input it should throw error

Comment: @user2916626 If there's more details, please edit your question. Added your comment to question.

Comment: @stribizhev (?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}) worked Thank you

Comment: @user2916626: I posted an answer explaining various options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to match *whole*, integer numbers from 1 till 1,000, you can use

```
^(?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})$
```

Or, to match separate numbers inside a larger string (with word boundaries `\b`):

```
\b(?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})\b
```

And if the numbers may appear in-between letters, other digits, or `_`:

```
(?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ8gF2/1)

The anchors make sure the number equals the whole input string.

The regex matches...

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:1,000|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})` - 2 alternatives: `1,000` or `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`:

  - `[1-9]` - a digit from 1 to 9
  - `[0-9]{0,2}` - 0 or 2 digits from 0 to 9
- `$` - end of string